# Calculate amount of coins

Tags: c++

I have the assignment from ZyLab

> Given six values representing counts of silver dollars, half dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, output the total amount as dollars and cents. The variable totalAmount is used to represent the total amount of money.
>
> Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved by executing results once before all other cout statements.
>
> Ex: If the input is: 5 3 4 3 2 1
>
> where 5 is the number of silver dollars, 3 is the number of half-dollars, 4 is the number of quarters, 3 is the number of dimes, 2 is the number of nickels, and 1 is the number of pennies, the output is: Amount: $5.66
>
> For simplicity, assume input is non-negative.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double totalAmount;
    int dollars;
    int halfDollars;
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;

    /* Type your code here. */
    /* get input */
    cin >> dollars;
    cin >> halfDollars;
    cin >> quarters;
    cin >> dimes;
    cin >> nickels;
    cin >> pennies;

    /* calculate totalAmount */
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    halfDollars = halfDollars * 0.5;
    quarters = quarters * 0.25;
    dimes = dimes * 0.10;
    nickels = nickels * 0.05;
    pennies = pennies * 0.01;
    totalAmount = dollars + halfDollars + quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
    /* output results */
    cout << "Amount: " << totalAmount << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is wrong? Could you show the expectation and the actual result?

Comment: Don't use floating-point math for currency calculations. Use integer math with the smallest currency denomination (in this case cents) being the base unit.

Comment: Hint: an `int` is an _integer_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables should be of type `float`.

Rewrite your code as following:

```
float dollars;
float halfDollars;
float quarters;
float dimes;
float nickels;
float pennies;
```

When you are converting for example half dollars, 3 half dollars * 0.5 is 1.5, but it can't be stored inside integer variable, so you need the variable to be of type `float`.

So when compiler is executing this piece of code;

```
/* calculate totalAmount */
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
halfDollars = halfDollars * 0.5;
quarters = quarters * 0.25;
dimes = dimes * 0.10;
nickels = nickels * 0.05;
pennies = pennies * 0.01;
```

it stores floating point value inside an integer declared variable, so compiler naturally casts it to integer type, producing incorrect output.

Comment: I think you had mistaken your expected result, if you have 5 dollars, 3 half dollars = 1.5 dollars, 4 quarters = 1 dollar, 3 dimes = 0.30 dollars, 2 nickels = 0.1 dollar, 1 penny = 0.01 dollar; it means 5 + 1.5 + 1 + 0.30 + 0.1 + 0.01 = 7.91 dollars.

Comment: @prud1 5.66$ is not the correct output from given inputs, it is 7.91 $ indeed.

Comment: Okay, I will ask my professor.Thank you again!

Comment: @prud1 No need to ask your professor, do the maths yourself, how much money would you have if you had that amount of coins.

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but I thought I was wrong.I will ask my professor about the mistake in Zybook

Comment: @prud1 If my answer was helpful I would be grateful if you could accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: i am sorry but how?)